# Apache airflow vs puckle airflow image

Tags: airflow-scheduler, airflow

I am currently using puckel airflow but now the apache airflow image is also available.
Which one is better and reliable. And given I need to start from scratch, which option would be better?

Answer (score 1):

Official. Puckel is no longer updated

Answer (score 0):

I started with puckel airlfow but as Javier mentioned its no longer updated. Last updated version was 1.10.9. Its easier to start with this image and following updates and mimicking required behaviours from official docker image you can build on it.